# Rails 4, Devise, CanCan and rails_admin issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan, rails-admin

I've been trying to set up rails_admin and to work with Rails 4.0.4, but unfortunately I ran across some issues. I have a devise generated User model with admin added as boolean afterwards. But even if the User is admin and needs to access the rails_admin panel, I get unauthorized access. It's like the current user cannot be passed in the ability.rb properly. Not sure if this is a Rails 4 issue or I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the code, with a little (ugly?) workaround that works, but I need a more elegant solution. Thanks.

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
      user = User.current # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.admin? 
        can :manage, :all
        can :access, :rails_admin # needed to access RailsAdmin
        can :dashboard            # dashboard access
      else
        can :read, :all
      end
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable     

  def self.current
    Thread.current[:user]
  end      

  def self.current=(user)
    Thread.current[:user] = user
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    User.current = current_user
  end
end
```

And, of course, I have this in **rails_admin.rb** enabled.

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with :cancan
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Cancan is not ready for rails4 so far. You can use it, but you can expect some issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it works, but you first need a Devise model before adding rails_admin.

Also, this needs to be enabled in rails_admin initializer:

config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

Comment: I had the same issue, adding config.current_user_method(&:current_user) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things which I notice, which are strange (not sure whether any of them is the core problem)

1) You don't authenticate anywhere.

You ApplicationContoller should have:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

And you do this (which I believe you don't need to do in Devise).

```
 before_filter :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    User.current = current_user
  end
```

2) Did you try to restart your server?

I believe RailsAdmin doesn't reload automatically (you either need to hack a special hack - https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/How-to:-Reloading-RailsAdmin-Config-Automatically or restart a server)

Comment: I don't think it needs to :authenticate_user! because I'm signing in via Devise form, then trying to open the /admin. The thing is, it doesn't pass the current user/session or something like that. I did exactly what it says here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancan and other sources too, before posting. I'm afraid it has something to do with my Rails version. It works with the solution with my original post, but not with the official guide. Will check the reload too, thanks. :)